# Add script in the controller execute function of custom controller

Tags: magento2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                require(['jquery'],function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                   alert('ok');
                });
            });
//$("#popup-modal<?= $currentproduct_id; ?>").closeModal();</script>
```

I want to add this script in controller execute function but getting error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Please do guide me something where am i wrong

Comment: share controller execute method's code

Comment: i have written above script in execute function

Comment: have you added something to return your script for render?

Answer (score 3):

If your `execute()` method in the controller outputs whatever code directly, there is no layout rendered and also there are no javascript libraries loaded.

It's better to create a to create a layout xml file for your controller and a phtml template and include the javascript code there. That will work unless you remove in your layout xml the blocks which are loading the javascript libraries.